# Why is flexbox, justify-content with vendor prefixes not working in safari?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari

The goal is to position the image to the right of it's container using `display: flex;` and `justify-content: right;`. The following code works fine in chrome and firefox but in all the safari versions I've tested it doesn't.

Things I've tried:

1. Checked [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=justify-content) which indicated it should work in all versions I've tested.
2. Run the css through [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) and added those.
3. Tested adding the css inline, with no change.
4. Turned styling on and off in the browser dev tools to check: everything works as expected except the flexbox styling in safari.
5. Isolated the code to rule out conflicts.
6. Tried multiple versions of safari including 9.1.2 (forgot to check actual version number for others but they were updated newer devices running catalina and latest iOS so assuming safari 13.x or 14.x).

Here is the [jsfiddle demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/capo1/mu0s4qot/2/)

Here is the html and css source code:

HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Safari - Flexbox Issue</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container container-nav"></div>
            <div class="container container-home">
                <img alt="tree image - should be far right of container" src="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/3-31530_vector-clip-art-cedar-tree-clip-art.png">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .container {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
    
    .container-nav {
        height: 80px;
    }
    
    .container-home {
        height: 40%;
        padding: 2em 4em 0 0;
      
        /* begin flexbox stuff */
      
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: right;
            -ms-flex-pack: right;
                justify-content: right;
    }
    
    img {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely the styling should be **justify-content: flex-end** to get the content to be aligned to the right.

Note that this will have a different layout if you do flex-direction:column - but for simple layouts - flex-start equates to the start of the row (left in a ltr layout) and flex-end equates to the end (right).

```
.container-home {
    height: 40%;
    padding: 2em 4em 0 0;
  
    /* begin flexbox stuff */
  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

and here is an image of the jsfiddle with those changes made and teh expected aligned right image
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved it. I wonder why `right` was working in the other browsers. [Found this article] (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/); in the `justify-content` section it says that `right` will act like `start` if it doesn't make sense with the `flex-direction`. So I tested explicitly setting `flex-direction` to `row` and trying `right` again but that didn't work. Just curious really but any insight into this?

Comment: no -sorry - I have no idea - flex-start / end are all I use and  just note that if ites flex-direction: column - then that will equate to top/ bottom instead of left / right.